# Listbox scrolls by Header of grouped entries

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox

I got a grouped Listbox. If I scroll - it behaves like expected that it scrolls by the headers of the groupings. But if there are too many entries it just skips them and instead scrolls to the next header. How to stop this behaviour.